# Como adicionar elementos na Queue (Fila) continuamente?

Tags: c#, winforms, thread, fila, fila-thread

Abaixo tenho um código que ele precisa fazer o seguinte: Criar uma thread, depois inicia-la. Quando inicia a thread, de acordo com o tempo (tempo randômico) o programa adiciona um valor na fila, depois de adicionado na fila, ele precisa mostrar quantos elementos tem na fila. Porém, quando executado, o programa não passa de 1 elemento na fila (mesmo já tendo passado o tempo para ser adicionado outro elemento). Como solucionar esse problema?

```
namespace MultiThreads
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Queue<int> FilaClientes = new Queue<int>();
        List<Thread> lt = new List<Thread>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private static void UpdateFila(TextBox tx, Queue<int> Fila)
        {
            tx.Text = Fila.Count.ToString();
        }

        private void AdicionaClientesFila(TextBox tx)
        {
            Stack<int> TempoParaFila = new Stack<int>();
            Random TempoVaria = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks & 
                                            0x0000FFFF);
            TempoParaFila.Push(TempoVaria.Next(1, 1001));
            int Aux = TempoParaFila.Pop();
            Thread.Sleep(Aux);

            //acima é descrito o valor em tempo para 
            //chegar alguém na fila

            Random ItensFila = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks & 
                                            0x0000FFFF);
            Stack<int> NovoCliente = new Stack<int>();
            NovoCliente.Push(ItensFila.Next(1, 1001));
            FilaClientes.Enqueue(NovoCliente.Pop());
            //Acima é adicionado a quantidade de itens do cliente

            if (txtboxTamanhoFila.InvokeRequired)
            {
                MethodInvoker m = new MethodInvoker(() => UpdateFila(tx, 
                                                     FilaClientes));
                tx.Invoke(m);
            }
            else
            {
                UpdateFila(tx, FilaClientes);
            }

            Application.DoEvents();
        }

        private void btnInicia_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach(Thread t in lt)
            {
                t.Start();
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }

        private void btnCriar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lt.Add(new Thread(() => 
                        AdicionaClientesFila(txtboxTamanhoFila)));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solução rápida** utilizar uma fila concorrente estática.

```
private static ConcurrentQueue<int> FilaClientes = new Queue<int>();
```

**Considerações**

1. Evite usar new Thread(). Ao criar uma nova thread, ela será criada em um core do processador e a carga não será distribuida. Ou seja, dependendo do processamento processos nesse core serão afetados e o desempenho em geral cairá. Sempre que possível utiliza Tasks (TPL https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming). O pessoal do .net resolveu isso muito 
   bem.
2. Ao invés de sempre disparar uma nova thread (ou task) no click, tu podes na criação do form iniciar uma task que ficará dentro de um looping while olhando para fila. Quando tiver um item na fila ele, processa.
3. Não entendi o uso do stack no método AdicionaClientesFila. A instrução é Sleep(RandomTime), Enqueue(RandomValue).

   ```
       var time = new Random().Next(minValue: 200, maxValue: 5000);
       Task.Delay(millisecondsDelay: time);

       var item = new Random().Next(minValue: 100, maxValue: 10000);
       FilaClientes.Enqueue(item: item);
   ```
4. Te sugiro ler o style guid do .net (variáveis locais iniciam com letra minúscula. Utilizar var para variáveis locais). https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/

Se ficar com dúvida, detalha mais o teu objetivo.

Comment: O objetivo é simular a fila de uma loja, porém com sua resposta eu consegui encontrar uma solução